# MWPhotoBrowser - Images moving inside view

Tags: ios, objective-c, mwphotobrowser

I am sure this is an easy question, but I am lost.  I have MWPhotoBrowser and a bunch of photos loaded into the browser.  Everything works beautifully, except if  I click on an image in the browser and drag it around the screen it moves everywhere and repositions the image.  Essentially I just want to stop if from dragging around all together.

Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues causing this problem:

1. Autolayout was turned off.  Since I wanted it to remain off I had to create a work around with #2.
2. The content appears to be sized to the View.  In my case the view height was much larger than the available display area on the screen.   To work around the issue I used another view sized to the viewable area and added the browser to that view rather than the super view.